# Wordpress, Redirect to different pages depending login credentials

Tags: wordpress

I am planning a project and writing down steps.

I need to know if it is possible to redirect user depending on login credentials using **wordpress** like below .
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WordPress has an expansive list of [Action Hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [Filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). These allow you to add/remove and modify functionality or output programatically.

There is a filter called [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) that you can tie to user roles or anything else you'd like.

```
function role_based_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    // Make sure this is a valid user on this site
    if( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ){
        if( in_array( 'subscriber', $user->roles ) ){
            // If user is a Default Role Subscriber
            $redirect_to = site_url( '/custom-subscriber-page/' );
        } else if( in_array( 'teacher', $user->roles ) ){
            // If user is a Custom Role of "Teacher"
            $redirect_to = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=teacher-custom-page' );
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'role_based_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```